# Nested XPath iteration possible?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, nested, iteration

I have a XML file template like this that comes from some IC chips, I want to be able to store each Pins Test type datas as an array so later I can draw it on a cartesian graph.

The data structure is like this:
`<NUMBER></NUMBER>` is name of the IC's particular pin
`<Curve Count="">` is number of tests done to a pin
`<Type></Type>` is type of test

and there are some voltage values and current values that I have to put in an array so I can use it later.

Anyway! My question is how can I get these values? I do not ask for a direct answer (but it is appriciated) but some guide that make me to find the thread is really appriciated.

EDIT: If somone kindly give me a code to have 3 voltage and 3 current values from A1 I can easily get the idea and continue myself.

This XML looks likes this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Document>
  <Device>NEC555</Device>
  <Pins Count="3">
    <Pin>
      <Number>A1</Number>
      <Curves Count ="3">
        <Curve>
          <Type>PreStress</Type>
          <VIPairs Count="3">
            <VIPair>
              <Voltage>-2</Voltage>
              <Current>-0.003</Current>
            </VIPair>
            <VIPair>
              <Voltage>-1</Voltage>
              <Current>-0.002</Current>
            </VIPair>
            <VIPair>
              <Voltage>-0</Voltage>
              <Current>-0.001</Current>
            </VIPair>
          </VIPairs>
        </Curve>
        <Curve>
          <Type>PreFail</Type>
          <VIPairs Count="3">
            <VIPair>
              <Voltage>-2</Voltage>
              <Current>-0.003</Current>
            </VIPair>
            <VIPair>
              <Voltage>-1</Voltage>
              <Current>-0.002</Current>
            </VIPair>
            <VIPair>
              <Voltage>-0</Voltage>
              <Current>-0.001</Current>
            </VIPair>
          </VIPairs>
        </Curve>
        <Curve>
          <Type>PostFail</Type>
          <VIPairs Count="0">
          </VIPairs>
        </Curve>
      </Curves>
    </Pin>
    <Pin>
      <Number>B1</Number>
      <Curves Count ="3">
        <Curve>
          <Type>PreStress</Type>
          <VIPairs Count="3">
            <VIPair>
              <Voltage>-3</Voltage>
              <Current>-0.005</Current>
            </VIPair>
            <VIPair>
              <Voltage>-1</Voltage>
              <Current>-0.002</Current>
            </VIPair>
            <VIPair>
              <Voltage>-0</Voltage>
              <Current>-0.001</Current>
            </VIPair>
          </VIPairs>
        </Curve>
        <Curve>
          <Type>PreFail</Type>
          <VIPairs Count="3">
            <VIPair>
              <Voltage>-3</Voltage>
              <Current>-0.003</Current>
            </VIPair>
            <VIPair>
              <Voltage>-1</Voltage>
              <Current>-0.002</Current>
            </VIPair>
            <VIPair>
              <Voltage>-0</Voltage>
              <Current>-0.001</Current>
            </VIPair>
          </VIPairs>
        </Curve>
        <Curve>
          <Type>PostFail</Type>
          <VIPairs Count="0">
          </VIPairs>
        </Curve>
      </Curves>
    </Pin>
  </Pins>
</Document>
```

Comment: Because XPath 1.0 node set is a unique unordered node set, there is no way to express an hierarchy structure like the one you want to group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much as I like using LINQ and `XDocument`, this is a case where XPath is simpler.

Given your XML, this XPath finds all of the `VIPair` elements under a `Pin` element with a given `Number` and under a `Curve` element with a given `Type`:

```
/Document/Device/Pins/Pin[Number='A1']/Curves/Curve[Type='PreStress']/VIPairs/VIPair
```

Using an `XmlDocument`, the code to get your three voltage and current values would look like this:

```
string number = "A1";
string type = "PreStress"
string xpath = string.Format(
   "/Document/Device/Pins/Pin[Number='{0}']/Curves/Curve[Type='{1}']/VIPairs/VIPair",
   number,
   type);
foreach (XmlElement viPair in doc.SelectNodes(xpath))
{
   string current = viPair.SelectSingleNode("Current").Value;
   string voltage = viPair.SelectSingleNode("Voltage").Value;
}
```

Using an XDocument, the code would be:

```
var values = doc.XPathSelectElements(xpath)
   .Select(x => new { Voltage = x.Element("Voltage").Value(),
                      Current = x.Element("Current").Value() });
```

Unless your document's been previously validated against a schema, you may want to make the last node test in the XPath `VIPair[Current and Voltage]`, so that the code doesn't fail if there's a `VIPair` element that's missing one of those child elements.  (Alternatively, you might actually *want* the code to throw an exception if that happens; it really depends on the quality of the source data.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked very nice! I just had to edit in your coud .Value to .InnerText

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx)

For your particular case it would probably look something like

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("yourFilePath");

var data = (from pins in doc.Element("Pins").Descendants
            from pin in pins.Element("Pin")
            from curve in pin.Element("Curves").Element("Curve")
            from pair in curve.Element("VIPairs").Descendants.Descendants()
            select new {
                          Voltage = pair.Element("Voltage").Value(),
                          Current = pair.Element("Current").Value()
        });
```

That code has not been tested

Comment: Thanks, I tried this code and fixed typos but it returns null. Would you please take another look? I couldn't fix your code to work yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some LINQ-to-XML, like this:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var data = from pin in doc.Descendants("Pin")
            select new
            {
                Number = pin.Element("Number").Value,
                Curves =
                    from curve in pin.Element("Curves").Descendants("Curve")
                    select new
                    {
                        Type = curve.Element("Type").Value,
                        VIPairs =
                            from pair in curve.Descendants("VIPair")
                            select new
                            {
                                Voltage = pair.Element("Voltage").Value,
                                Current = pair.Element("Current").Value
                            }
                    }
            };
```